# How to get Google search results in Android using Java?

Tags: java, android, api, google-search

I want to add Google search functionality to my Android app. I want to create one layout where I can display results from different branches (Books, Videos, Maps, etc). How can I get results programmatically? Any API and samples?

Answer (score 1):

[Google Web Search](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/#fonje) would be the API that you are looking for.

In the search request, you can specify a latitude and longitude with the text to get a reference to the nearby places, if you are doing a location based search. [Here](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/reference.html#_fonje_local) is the reference to the parameters for the search request.

You can simply make a http call and parse the JSON response when it comes back.

However, [CustomSearch](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview) is the new API that Google encourages you to use instead of the deprecated one.