# Get Google search results and show in android app

Tags: android, google-search

I want to display google search results in my android app,When the user type word in editText and click search button to get **google search results** and shown in inside my app.I have no experience to do this. please help me anyone

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356978/how-to-get-google-search-results-in-android-using-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Google search results in Android using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356978/how-to-get-google-search-results-in-android-using-java)

Comment: I know, using custom google search api ,but any one help how to use custom search api to get search result using android

Rather than custom search api ?

Comment: http://www.vancura.cz/?p=578

In this site having the custom search api tutorial but it not working for me

Answer (score 5):

```
private static final String GOOGLE_SERACH_URL = "https://www.google.com/search?q=";
```

Then simply append the key you want to search on google after the URL and load your query string in a WebView.

```
   webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);
   webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   webView.loadUrl(GOOGLE_SERACH_URL + searchKey);
```

Working example

https://github.com/hiteshsahu/Android-Universal-Web-Content-Loader

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Intent` class with the action web search.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH); 
String keyword= "your query here";    
intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, keyword);    
startActivity(intent);
```

For better learning you can follow [example program.](https://dzone.com/articles/android-%E2%80%93-how-implement-google)

Comment: Hi @SN Singh if i use above code, it take me to browser, that i not want, when the user click the search button get the results then shown in the same activity